# Override default Auth routes in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I need to custom routes of `Auth::routes();`, I can not find them, try search in  Router.php

```
 Vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php
```

But I didn't find them!

Comment: The auth routes are in the `laravel/ui` package in the [AuthRouteMethods.php](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php) file. If you have installed the package in your project, you will find them at: `/your-proyect/vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Thank you so much! found it

Answer (score 14):

In **Laravel(5.+, 6,7,8) ui** `Auth::routes();` uses a `function auth()` defined in `vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php`

You can copy the content of this function and paste it directly in your `web.php` **route file** file and update as you want like below or something else.

```
// Login Routes...
Route::get('admin-login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('admin-login', 'Admin\LoginController@login');

// Logout Routes...
Route::post('admin-logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('admin-register', 'Admin\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('admin.register');
Route::post('admin-register', 'Admin\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('admin-password/reset', 'Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.request');
Route::post('admin-password/email', 'Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email');
Route::get('admin-password/reset/{token}', 'Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
Route::post('admin-password/reset', 'Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('admin.password.update');

// Password Confirmation Routes...
Route::get('admin-password/confirm', 'Admin\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('admin.password.confirm');
Route::post('admin-password/confirm', 'Admin\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm');

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('admin-email/verify', 'Admin\VerificationController@show')->name('admin.verification.notice');
Route::get('admin-email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Admin\VerificationController@verify')->name('admin.verification.verify');
Route::post('admin-email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('admin.verification.resend');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Auth::routes()` function takes an optional parameter `$options`. You can manually disable certain routes like this:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

Comment: Bingo... Exactly what I needed to override

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan route:list
```

Please try with this artisan command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to override `Auth::routes()`. Remove it from your route file and put your own custom route there. Auth facade have routes() method and it call auth()  method from Router class to register Auth routes.